# How to get results from 1000 to 1000 unless var = 0

Tags: php, algorithm

I've a query where num_rows return one million of records. I need to iterate trough this one million of records by 1000 I mean start in 0 to one million and every 1000 generate a otuput (Excel File):

```
Excel1: will contain records 1~1000
Excel2: will contain records 1001~2000
Excel3: will contain records 2001~3000
Excel14: will contain records 3001~4000
```

and so on until I reach one million. I think in use a `while()` but I'm not secure at all, any help?

Comment: why do you need 1000 variables after all?

Comment: @varnie I need to create a Excel file for each 1000 records, a Excel with one million will be very high and will load the server, I wrote 1000 as a example should be defined in a var

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Has the query already been run and you have 1 million rows returned?  Or are you trying to set up a PHP loop to query the database for 1000 rows at a time?  And what do you mean by "while() is not secure?"

Comment: Hi @john-conde I can't post anything in Stackoverflow due to qualification obtained here, can you please tell me how can I fix this? I need to answer others things and can't :-(

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're querying a db, something like this should work:

```
$start = 0;
$end = 1000;

$qstring= 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable ORDER BY col1 LIMIT ?, ?';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $qstring);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $start, $end);
do{
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($co11, $col2);
 while($stmt->fetch()){
   //do something with $col1, $col2
 }

 $count = $stmt->num_rows
 $start = $end + 1;
 $end = $start +1000;

} while($count == 1000);
```